# Firemonkey loading multiple images memory overload

Tags: image, delphi, memory, firemonkey

I try to write a photo editor with FireMonkey. I have 50 TImage components that were created at runtime. If I load a large image (about 3 MB) into these components, I get a 'memory overload' error.

This is my image transfer code ;

```
img1:=(sender as timage).Name;
strm:=TMemoryStream.Create;
(data.Source as timage).Bitmap.SaveToStream(strm);
(sender as timage).Bitmap.LoadFromStream(strm);
strm.Free;
```

Comment: Please show the actual error message

Comment: ...and more code would help too, as would OS details.

Comment: This is like trying to pour a full gallon of milk into a small cup and wondering why it's overflowing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are probably loading camera photos (JPG format).  These are likely ~8-10 megapixel images.  When loading to a TBitmap you lose the JPG compression so they are no longer 3MB files but (#MP X 24bpp).  For a 10MP image that makes about 30MB RAM requirement.  For 50 such images, that's 1.5GB.  On 32-bit Windows this will likely push you past your system's addressable memory limit.

What you need to think about is whether or not you need to have fifty full-sized images open and in RAM at once.  Unless you are doing enormous, Photoshop-scale graphic design there is really no need to have 500 million pixels of data in RAM at once.  Photoshop uses its own built-in disk cache system to manage this problem.  If you really need this scale of flexibility then you will need to implement something similar.

This is all, of course, assuming that you aren't leaking memory.  1.5GB, although grossly large, should fit without issue on a 64-bit system, even in a 32-bit process (assuming you compiled with `{$SetPeFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}`).  If this is the case, then you need to start looking at tools like [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) that can help trace memory leaks in your program.

Comment: Regarding the final paragraph, only if the 32 bit process was built large address aware. And even then, memory fragmentation could be a problem.